# Permanently storing and displaying user input for others to view

Tags: javascript, database, html

I am new to javascript, and I'm building a web app where I would like the user to be able to enter the species of a fish along with some specific information, and then have that information permanently saved for future users to view. Is this possible/what would be the best approach?

Comment: You need to show what you tried so far and explain why it didn't work.  This is way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to learn a server side language:

- C# ASP.NET
- PHP
- Python
- JavaScript (Node JS)
- Ruby On Rails

Then you will need to learn a database:

- MySQL
- MSSQL
- Oracle SQL
- MongoDB (document orientated storage)
- PostgreSQL

Then you can create you UI using several tools:

- jQuery
- Knockout (my favourite UI binding library)
- Angular

Each server side language will have a toolkit for interacting with several databases

- ASP.NET has EntityFramework (ADO.NET) and NHibernate
- PHP has PDO

Once you have learnt 1 of each of these things (in the case of the UI tools several, jQuery and knockout work well together) then you can create you Web App where things will be saved.

Here are a few IDEs you can use:

- Visual Studio
- Notepad++
- NetBeans
- WebStorm

An approach to building web applications that I like to take (recently adopted) is to build up the UI front end in a way the user would like using `Knockout Js` and `Bootstrap` (a responsive html and css framework). Once I'm happy with the `viewModels` and `models` used front end and the way in which I would like my data present to the client side JavaScript I will then develop the backend in accordance with this.

My preference is to use C# ASP.NET because of the power of C# and the eco system surrounding it. But it is dependant on what you find the easiest to use and enjoy the most.

Comment: You left out Ruby on Rails and Postgresql, these are among the most frequently used tools for building web apps.

Comment: So I did, give me a sec

Comment: Some would say that Ruby on Rails isn't a language, but that it's a framework.  In reality it is a Domain Specific Language, not a framework like Symfony or Laravel.

Comment: Yeah, just been reading up on it, built off the rails core language and developed around the web

Comment: Let's completely ignore Java (EE)?

Comment: The core language is ruby, and rails is a DSL for web development.

Comment: Ummmmm, yes, i personally hate Java to the end of the world and back, not having it on my post.

Comment: @PeterWooster yeah sorry, I'm pretty tired, I meant ruby

Comment: I used Java including Struts, Spring, Hibernate, JSF and a lot of other alphabet soup since 1996 and gave it up for lent in 2011 and have rejected it and all its pomps.

Comment: You did include Netbeans, which is my regular editor for PHP. I use RubyMine for Ruby, they are both written in Java.

Comment: Ahhh, yeah but you can use Netbeans for JavaScript to though, I know it is a written in Java but hey. Thats why I run it inside a VM :P